Integration tests fail due to external components... but code needs to be merged to main
Our CI/CD pipeline requires integration tests to pass in order to merge a branch to main.
A team I've started working with has had an issue with integration tests failing at times due to external systems over which we have no control. This causes some frustration as code changes build up until the external system returns to normal operation.
Is this a problem that has common solutions, and if so what are they? Or do the solutions tend to be unique to the environment such that it would be difficult to offer general advice or point to standard patterns for dealing with this dilemma?
Some context for our situation: the integration test calls an API we have control over, and that API in turn calls the external component. In an ideal world, maybe it could fall back to a mock server for the external component when it's down; but that would be difficult to implement due to the fact that it would require code changes in the application to enable behavior that I don't think you would want to put there. For example, you wouldn't want to deploy code like that to production. You could make it conditional based on environment, but then maybe you are beginning to get into an area of complexity that outweighs the benefit.
It seems this has to be a common problem... but I don't have enough of a background in QA & Testing to know whether it's one that comes with standard solutions.

I don't think it's appropriate for your build pipeline to rely on an external service that could gate your ability to build and deploy changes.
Let's take an extreme example. Your CI/CD pipeline gates production deployments. You have a critical production defect that needs to be fixed quickly. However, the third-party service is, for some reason, offline. The third-party service provider limits your ability to restore your service. A defect unrelated to this third-party service can't be fixed until the third-party service is restored.
I recommend that your CI/CD pipeline mock out external services you have no control over. It would be best to mock out the expected cases but also cover outages and other error conditions from the external service and assert that your system handles external failures gracefully.
You wouldn't need to change the API that you have control over, assuming that the API is properly parameterized. If you've hard-coded the calls to the external component, you'll need to extract that to the configuration. You'd be able to adjust the configuration to use calls to the real service or to the mocked service that can be running in your test environment. This is a good practice, anyway.
I don't think it's bad to have automated tests that use an external service, especially if the external service provider offers an instance of their service for development or testing. The only issue is if those tests gate the ability for you to make assertions about your system and deploy changes.

(Thomas Owens's answer is quite good, I will go in the same direction, but offer some different info/suggestions).
Firstly, in this answer we will be differentiating Integrated Tests from Integration Tests, in the spirit of the article Beware the Integrated Tests Scam. What you described is Integrated Tests, which have some value, but several problems.
Owens's answer goes into a good path suggesting moving towards Acceptance Tests, where you will exercise your code's behavior, under a controlled state.
For web service, a good tool is MockServer.
It's lightweight and can be run in several contexts (binary, Docker, programatically in Java or Javascript, etc).
Here an example of usage of MockServer, which can be easily implemented in a build pipeline: https://chatgpt.com/share/d6f3228f-1af6-4bd3-9b3a-588c41320551
Following Ownens's advice, you will simply have to inject the MockServer instance info (URL, access token,...) to your access to be able to access it.
But then with this will you be losing the interactions with your downstream (which you don't control). What if what you are mocking has nothing to do with the actual downstream? Your tests will go green and your service will blow up in production.
Then it's the moment of doing actual Integration Testing: Assessing if the downstream is able to perform the operations you need/expect.
A good tool for this is Pact, specially with the Bidirectional approach. The previous link has the proper documentation, but the TLDR version is:

Your unit tests will generate a list of requests/responses pairs, describing the interactions you need/expect, called Consumer Contract;
Pact read your downstream (here called Provider) specification (e.g. Swagger/OpenAPI) and check if it can fulfil the Consumer Contract.

In this way, you will know the API you will actually connect can be used for your needs.
Of course, if the API mismatches with the specification, the tests above are useless. To actually assess integration against the actual API code, you would need to the Consumer-Driven Approach, but this requires changes in the Provider code/build pipeline - if you can collaborate with them, you will have more certainty.
A supplementary step would be Pact's can-i-deploy, where you will verify at the deployment moment if the integration tests were successful.

What happens when the external component goes down in production?
If the answer is the use case isn't that critical and folks just wait for it to come back up, maybe you can move the test to run continuously against production (i.e. as a synthetic monitor). That way it won't block code deploys but will still alert you when there are problems.
This requires accepting the tradeoff of potentially increased time to detection and increased time to recovery, so it only can really be considered for non-critical use cases.
If the use case is critical (e.g. human safety is on the line) I think your current setup is probably best (though why can't the external component behave more like it does in prod?), with the tradeoff being poorer developer experience like you're running into.

It's a new application that is not in production yet, and to be honest I don't think we know if it will behave this way in production. It could, for all we know. But I guess my position is that the issue is being handled with the 3rd party and will eventually be resolved, so in the meantime it probably doesn't make sense to let this issue block our progress as though it were a problem with our code when it is not.

I see. If you're setup for it you might still have the option to run the test continuously out of band on whatever environment the CI/CD pipeline is currently targeting (like a synthetic monitor). That plus good enough telemetry around the external component should probably be enough to distinguish true app code issues from it being down, all while not blocking code deploys.

I think that makes insanely good sense.
